# C++ different class getters

Tags: c++, oop

I am relatively new to C++ OO:

How is this getter:

```
class A {
  B b;
public:
  B const &getB() const {
    return b;
  }
};
```

different from this one?

```
class A {
  B b;
public:
  const B &getB() const {
    return b;
  }
};
```

and this one?

```
class A {
  B b;
public:
  const B &getB() {
    return b;
  }
};
```

and which one is correct?

*Edit*
This question has an answer here: Look for "consistent const" in http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const

Comment: 1 and 2 mean the same thing, and both are correct.  3 is not technically incorrect, however since `getB()` isn't modifying the `A` instance, it makes sense for the function to be `const`, which allows it to be called on `const A` object instances (or references, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your comments but I think this question had an answer

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `const` applies on what stands before him (on his left) or, if nothing is before it, it applies on what stands after it (on his right). Your 3 cases are all correct in their uses.

You can refer to this excellent article to learn more about const-correctness : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html

Comment: thanks, but I didn't see this had an answer